# Angular UI select2 - How to stop automatic sorting?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui

The following data is attached to [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) via [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-select2): ([Live example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5X7s8WZPVw7Z9gVWDjK3?p=preview))

JS:

```
$scope.items = [
  {id: 1, text: 'elephant'}, 
  {id: 2, text: 'desk'}, 
  {id: 3, text: 'car'}, 
  {id: 4, text: 'boat'}, 
  {id: 5, text: 'apple'}
];
$scope.selected = [];
```

HTML:

```
<select ui-select2 
        multiple 
        ng-model="selected" 
        data-placeholder="Please select..." 
        style="width:200px">
  <option></option>
  <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</option>
</select>
```

However, every time item is selected, it sorts the selected items by `id`. For example, if you choose "apple" and then "boat", the `selected` items will be "boat" and "apple" (in this order!).

How could I preserve the order and disable this automatic sorting?

Comment: Does this occur with vanilla JS in Select2 or ONLY with AngularUI?

Comment: I am not at all sure why this is occurring. Can you open a ticket on the project?

Comment: @ProLoser: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/issues/406

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it preserves the order if you use `ng-options` instead of doing an `ng-repeat` for each of the items like seen [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/Iwkp2tbZZy0sPUfNh8yY)

All you have to do is delete this line:

```
<option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</option>
```

And then add a directive like this to your  tag:

```
ng-options="item.text for item in items"
```

This will make it so the entire item object gets appended to the selected list, instead of just the ID, so you will need to take that into account.

Comment: `ui-select2` is incompatible with `ng-options` and will create unusual behaviors.